# Replace the color of block in gray scale image in Python

Tags: python, image, python-2.7, opencv, image-processing

I have an Image of 128x128 pixels in which, there are 1024 blocks of 4x4 pixels each.

If the coordinates of the first block are`block1= im[0:4, 0:4]`, then I want to replace the colour of pixels into a specific pixel intensity(or colour),example-128.

So what I want to do is I want to change the colour of the image something like this-

```
block1=im[0:4,0:4]
block1.replace_colour=128
```

Note that the image is in the grayscale.Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do that like this:

```
colorValue = 150
im[0:4,0:4] = colorValue
```